# Troubles with View into a pageControl

Tags: ios, xcode, uipagecontrol

I have a a troubles with the views.
Sometimes loads like

[image]

And other times

[image]

The constraints are fixed
[image]

What is going bad ?
Thanks.

Comment: please check the frame of a table view.

Comment: the tableView is behind this view.

Comment: please check the frames when view loads correctly and when it loads disturbed. and make the frame same just like when it loads correctly.